# After detaching and reappending/prepending justification is lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grid-layout

I have a cool grid that depends on `text-align: justify`. I needed to reorder the items using javascript and after reordering and detaching and prepending them again I noticed that somehow the elements are not justified anymore.

Here's how it works:

```
<div id="g">
    <div>2</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <!-- These spans are here to keep the last line justified -->
    <!-- Makes no difference to the problem whether they are there or not -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var divs = $('#g div');

// The sorting doesn't contribute to the problem.
// This could be commented out.
divs.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = parseInt(a.innerHTML);
    b = parseInt(b.innerHTML);
    if(a > b) return 1;
    if(a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
});

// Remove comment from this last line to see what happens:
//divs.detach().prependTo($('#g'));
```

And the CSS:

```
#g {
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
}

div,
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

span {
    border: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3zLvemhc/2/

Is there a way to get the justification back? Why is it lost in the first place? I get this behavior with at least Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I actually cannot see the difference even when commenting out the javascript?

Comment: The fiddle posted is missing most of the code and actually doesn't demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. For some reason what I saw on my screen and that which I got a share link for were not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that after prepending, your elements don't have any white space between them.  You can fix that by adding some:

```
divs.detach().prependTo($('#g')).after(" ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3zLvemhc/1/